# NPE is thrown when a common table expression is referred from a subquery in a SELECT clause

Tags: sql, h2

Here is an example exposing the subject. It's quite synthetic so it might seem confusing.

There is a H2 database with two tables, `object_types` and `attributes`:

```
  attributes          object_types
--------------       --------------
object_type_id       object_type_id
attr_id
```

Both tables contain one record:

```
INSERT INTO object_types VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO attributes VALUES (1,2);
```

The following query checks if `object_types` has a record referred to by an attribute with `attribute_id = 2`:

```
SELECT
        attributes.object_type_id IN (SELECT object_types.object_type_id FROM object_types)
    FROM attributes
    WHERE attributes.attr_id = 2
```

The query works well. But if `object_types` is referred from a subquery through a common table expression, NPE will be thrown:

```
WITH cte (object_type_id) AS (
    SELECT object_type_id FROM object_types
) SELECT
        attributes.object_type_id IN (SELECT cte.object_type_id FROM cte)
    FROM attributes
    WHERE attributes.attr_id = 2

General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-196]
  java.lang.NullPointerException:
```

H2 v.1.4.196 is used.

Is it a bug in H2 or a standard limitation in usage of common table expressions with subqueries?

Comment: I would consider that a bug in H2

Comment: Maybe similar to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/__d0Tlrw538